How Do You Retreive And Update An Item Using Room Database In Jetpack Compose?
I'm trying to develop a simple note taking app in jetpack compose. I've successfully developed an application that takes in text field inputs and saves them using room database then displays them into a lazy column.
I've create the basic room files. Here they are:
The Note Entity takes one parameter (other than the id) called text.
@Entity
data class Note(

    val Text: String,

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0
)

The Doa has five functions. One for inserting a note, one for updating a note, one for deleting a note, one for retrieving all notes, and one for retrieving a note by it's id.
@Dao
interface NoteDao {

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertNote(note: Note)

    @Update
    suspend fun updateNote(note: Note)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteNote(note: Note)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM note")
    fun getAllNotes(): Flow<List<Note>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM note WHERE id = :id")
    fun getNoteById(id: Int): Flow<Note>
}

Here is the database as you'd expect.
@Database(
    entities = [Note::class],
    version = 1
)
abstract class NoteDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val noteDao: NoteDao
}

Here is the view model. It takes all of the Dao functions.
class NoteViewModel(private val noteDatabase: NoteDatabase): ViewModel() {

    fun insertNote(note: Note){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            noteDatabase.noteDao.insertNote(note)
        }
    }

    fun updateNote(note: Note){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            noteDatabase.noteDao.updateNote(note)
        }
    }

    fun deleteNote(note: Note){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            noteDatabase.noteDao.deleteNote(note)
        }
    }

    fun getAllNotes() = noteDatabase.noteDao.getAllNotes()
        .asLiveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext)

    fun getNoteById(id: Int) = noteDatabase.noteDao.getNoteById(id)
        .asLiveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext)

}

Here is the Main Page Composable. It contains a column that displays two text fields, one holds a variable called "textValue" and the other holds a variable called "updateValue". Beneath the text fields are two buttons. One successfully saves the value of the first text field and displays it in a lazy column, the other unsuccessfully updates the value of a saved note. Beneath buttons is a lazy column that displays the saved notes.
@Composable
fun MainPage(viewModel: NoteViewModel) {
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(50.dp)
    ) {

        val note = Note(
            Text = textValue
        )

        var noteList by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf<Note>())}

        viewModel.getAllNotes().observe(LocalLifecycleOwner.current) {
            noteList = it
        }

        NoteTextField(text = textValue, onTextChange = { textValue = it })

        NoteTextField(text = updateValue, onTextChange = { updateValue = it })

        Row {
            NoteButton(
                text = "Create",
                onClick = {
                    viewModel.insertNote(note)
                }

            )
            NoteButton(
                text = "Update",
                onClick = {
                        viewModel.updateNote(
                        note = Note(updateValue))
                }
            )
        }
        NoteList(noteList = noteList)
    }
}

Here the NoteList composable. It contains a lazy column, that holds a box that displays the saved note. When a box is pressed the saved note is displayed in the second text field.
@Composable
fun NoteList(
    noteList: List<Note>
    ) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(noteList){note ->
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    savedText = note.Text
                    updateValue = note.Text
                }
                .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Black)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(100.dp)
        ){
            Text(text = "${note.Text}    ${note.id}")
        }
    }}
}

I can't figure out how to update the saved note after it is displayed in the second text field.

I forget to mention, I did create an instance of the database in the Main Activity. I just didn't post it.

If you "forgot to mention" then you should [edit] your post to add it.

clickable sets savedText and updateValue which seem to be local variables of NoteList but they are nowhere declared. The same applies to MainPage where the declaration of textValue and updateValue is missing. Please add the declarations.

One issue is declaring the local variables as @Leviathan noted.
Another issue is that you need to pass an id to the click function of the button in order for the update to happen. An id is needed , otherwise the DB does not know which one to udpate.
In the following code, I modified it so that the update button checks the list of notes, and if its not empty, I choose to update the first note, by passing an id of 1, so that the update will happen on the first note only.

                onClick = {
                    if (noteList.isNotEmpty()) {
                        viewModel.updateNote(
                            Note(noteText = updateTextValue, id = 1)
                        )
                        println("Updating note")
                    }
                }


